# Read a file line by line for an exact match using perl script

Tags: perl, grep

I have written a `perl` script to read an input file line-by-line for a given search string. I have done two implementations using the inbuilt `perl` functions `grep` and `index`, but I'm not able to get the output for the exact string match.

My sample code, input file and the desired output is shown below. Please help me understand the issue with this script which can help me to get the required output.

**SAMPLE_CODE**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $myfile = "/path/to/the/file/list.txt";
my $details = "1234,5678";
my @required;

open FH, "$myfile" or die "Cannot open file for reading\n";
while(<FH>)
{
    $line = $_;
    chomp $line;
    @list = split(/\,/, $details);

    foreach my $var (@list)
    {
        chomp($var);
        #if (grep /$var/, $line)            # partially working
        if (index($line, $var) >= 0)        # partially working
        {
            my @arr = split(/[\:]/, $line);
            push (@required, $arr[0]);
        }
    }
}
close FH;

print "required array is @required \n";
```

**INPUT_FILE**

```
$>  cat /path/to/the/file/list.txt

CAT:1234,5678
RAT:12345,9871
```

**OUTPUT**

```
required array is CAT CAT RAT
```

**DESIRED_OUTPUT**

```
required array is CAT CAT
```

Here the problem is that, Since the variable `$details` has a string `1234`, the `grep` or `index` checks should not pass the search criteria for the second line in input file `list.txt` for `12345`.

How can i fix this issue for exact match?

Comment: In any language `Cannot open file for reading` is the canonical example of a useless error message.  Try: `open my $fh, '<', "$myfile" or die "$myfile: $!";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It already was indicated that your code will match partial pattern, it is not what you desire. You need implement exact match and regular expression has `\b` to indicate the boundary of element.

It is a good practice to include in the begin of the script

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

what allows to warn you about undesired effect of your code.

Perhaps for this case you can utilize `<>` (null handle/diamond operator) instead of opening filehandle, it simplifies the code and allows code's double usage as `script.pl list.txt` or `cat list.txt | script.pl`

NOTE: `@list = split(/,/, $details);` should be placed outside of loop to save CPU cycles

Please see the following snippet code producing desired output

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
# vim: ai ts=4 sw=4

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $details = "1234,5678";
my(@list, @required);

@list = split(/,/, $details);

while(<>) {
    for my $element ( @list ) {
        if( /\b$element\b/ ) {
            my @arr = split(/[:,]/, $_);
            push @required, $arr[0];
        }
    }
}

say "Required array is @required";
```

Output

```
Required array is CAT CAT
```

Reference:
[<>](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop),
[$_](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_special_variables.htm),
[split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split)

Comment: The OP has indicated that fields contain more than numbers, and for example dash `-`. This will trigger word boundary regex char `\b`.

Comment: @TLP -- it was not indicated in original question, I only see in the comments to your answer.

Comment: @PolarBear: Appreciate for your feedback about moving `@list = split(/,/, $details);` should be moved outside of the loop to save CPU cycles. I have incorporated this in my code.  Moreover, by changing the if condition to use the regex for boundary condition `\b`, my code is working. The change is: `if (grep /\b$var\b/, $line )`.  I will dive more into this regular expression and hope I will be able to build the logic for my deployment code from here on. Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: @PolarBear But you do see it now. `/\babc-def\b/` will match partially on `123-abc-def` for example. Your solution risks breaking the code. But as long as the OP doesn't care, why should we?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the matching you are doing, both `grep /$var/` and `index($line, $var)`  allows for lines to match partially. I.e.

```
12345
^^^^  <---- matches 1234
```

Much the same way that `/car/` would match `carpet`, or `scarlet` partially.

What you should probably do is isolate the numbers, put them in an array, and check it numerically. For example:

```
my ($name, @nums) = split /[:,]/, $line;     # split into all fields at once
for my $num (@nums) {
    for my $num2 (@list) {
        if ($num == $num2) {                 # check numerical equality
             push @required, $name;
        }
    }
}
```

Or if as your comment implies, your fields are strings, you can use `eq` to check for equality. Alternatively use anchors in your regex `/^$var$/` to force a complete match. `^` means beginning of line, and `$` end of line. For example:

```
"car" eq "carpet"     # false
"car" eq "car"        # true
"carpet" =~ /^car$/   # false
```

More efficiently, you can use a hash for the numbers to test for, for example

```
my %list = map { $_ => 1 } split /,/, $details;
...
if ($list{$num}) {        # check if the value is true
    push @required, $name;
}
```

Comment: Actually i have presented a very simplified data-set. The original data set is a very complex one hence the suggested solution may not apply. For example: the original data set is something like this: `CAT:1234-abc-xyz,5678-pqr-mno`. You can assume at least 10 more entries in the same line and there are at least 50 lines like this. I would appreciate if you could point the flaw in my solution and suggest a fix for same. I will be able to port it easily. Thanks!

Comment: @Yash That is the problem when you simplify too much. I added some alternatives for non-numerical strings. They are basically either use `eq` instead of `==`, or use anchors `/^$var$/`. Both solutions require you to split the string to isolate the fields. The tricky part would be if you have delimiters (commas `,` ) inside your fields, or quoted fields. In that case, you're going to have to use some other method of extracting your data.

Answer (score -1):

You need to print the 1st field of every line if its 2nd, 3rd etc. fields match certain criteria?

```
echo 'CAT:1234,5678\nRAT:12345,9871' |
perl -F'/:|,/' -lane 'foreach (@F) { push @required, $F[0] if /\b1234\b|\b5678\b/ }
                      print "The required array: @required"'
```

Output:

```
The required array: CAT CAT
```

`-F'/:|,/'` option tells Perl to split the fields of a line on either `:` or `,` and fill the special array `@F` with these fields: `$F[0]` gets the 1st field, `$F[1]` gets the 2nd and so on.

If any field of the line: `foreach (@F)` match 1234 or 5678: `if /\b1234\b|\b5678\b/`, then push the 1st field of the line onto the `@required` array: `push @required, $F[0]`.

To read the data from a file:

```
perl -F'/:|,/' -lane 'foreach (@F) { push @required, $F[0] if /\b1234\b|\b5678\b/ } 
                      END{ print "The required array: @required" }' yourData.txt
```